# Links from pwa open in webview instead of browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I use generated navigation (Google maps, Waze) links in PWA. Logically, it should prompt user to open link with navigation app (like in Chrome). But it does not prompt user to open with some app, and directly opens the link inside of webview.

Is there a way to open links directly in chrome or to prompt user to open with an app (without using intents).

Here are the pics.

[PWA directly opens this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUZ0S.jpg)

[Chrome prompts user to open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkmXD.jpg)

Comment: What is your "display" settings in the manifest.json ?

Comment: I set it to `standalone`, with `browser` option it works (I checked for Android devices only), but it opens the main pwa also in browser, and adds chrome logo to app's icon.

Comment: "adds chrome logo to app's icon" - If so, you perhaps did not install a PWA, but just a shortcut to your website. Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Yep, I checked again, you're right, I used "Add to home screen" option, but when setting "display" to `browser` in manifest.json, it doesn't even give an option to install the app)

Comment: The Chrome Lighthouse test will give you good hints on what you need to do to make your website a valid/installable PWA

Comment: Yep I checked with Lighthouse also, it says change display property from `browser` to one of these `fullscreen, standalone, minimal-ui`, which leads to the issue described above.

Comment: I have the same challenge. Did you find any solution to this?